# Unique account identifier / Several accounts with same email address possible?

Tags: customer, email, customer-account

We are a manufacturer of dance wear apparel.  Some of our customers have multiple businesses, for example,  one for dance and one for cheerleading.  The business owner wants to have two different accounts with us, separating the business lines.   But, they want to use the same email address for both accounts.

We are told that in using Magento, that condition would not be allowed, as   Magento uses the email address as the unique identifier for an account.

Is this true?   If so, has anyone ever run in to this issue.  Are there any add-on modules or plugins that would allow a different unique identifier to function as the logon.

Comment: I have used the Itabs Subaccounts extension for customers to manage several accounts, it's doing okay. Demo: http://subaccounts-demo.itabs.de/ (German only, sorry)

Answer (score 2):

It's doable. Actually did it a couple of times. You will need to find a good Magento implementation partner for this though.

But I'd take a look at what your customers actually need. I'm guessing they want a way to separate out their orders, which would be possible if you allow for a Purchase Order number to be defined in the checkout per order.

I would suggest you find a certified Magento Solution Specialist as consultant, they can help you with your requirements.